# Run sudo command from service

Tags: debian, sudo

I'm working in Debian 10.

I have a service that runs a Java application:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

The application may call system commands, one of them is `nmcli`. I need to run `nmcli con add` with sudo. Therefore I edited the sudoers' file to allow the user to run the command `nmcli` without being asked for the password. When I test my application, it works fine and it doesn't ask the password.

When I execute my application as a service, it fails to execute the `sudo` commands and tells that

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Though, my user is enabled to run those commands without inserting the password...

What's happening?

Comment: are you root? when you execute the application as a service you prolly run it as root.

Comment: No, I'd prefer - if possible - to run it as a sudoer user...